# PHP get variable from URL

Tags: php

I have an App using URLs such as

`/order?123` and I'm using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the variable but I want to change the URLs to a more readable form like

`/order/123`

How can I get `123`?

Answer (score 2):

Apache needs to know you want to run your script when such a request is seen.
Assuming your script is named order.php put this in a .htaccess file in the same directory as your script

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/order/(\d+)*$ ./order.php?id=$1
```

eg; /order/123   is treated as /order.php?id=123
you get that value with ..

```
echo $_REQUEST['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '/order/123';
echo substr($str, strrpos($str, '/') + 1);
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']:

```
<?php
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $var = substr(strrchr($uri, '/'), 1);
?>
```

As always, don't forget to check, sanitize, validate, escape this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a mistake in your `/order?123` URL, I'm assuming it should be using get variables so `/order?var=123`.  With that assumption the way to get variables from the URL is with [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)... like this...

```
$arrVariables = array();
parse_str($str, $arrVariables);
$arrVariables['var'];
```